can i modify data in a SQLAlchemy database using the terminal
Im working on a Flask application with SQLAlchemy for database management. I have a Role model defined in my models.py file, and I'm looking for a way to modify data in this model directly through the terminal. Here's a simplified version of my code:
# website/__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "iwonttellyou"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
    db.init_app(app)

    from .models import Role

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")

    return app


# website/models.py
from . import db

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "roles"

    def __init__(self, type, name):
        self.role_type = type
        self.role_name = name

    role_type = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    role_name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)

I want to be able to add, update, or delete roles directly through the terminal without interacting with the Flask app itself. What would be the best approach to achieve this? Are there any recommended tools or techniques I should consider for this task?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
i typed python command to enter python shell. After entering python shell i typed
from models import Role

File "", line 1, in 
File "website/models.py", line 2, in 
from . import db
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
this is the error message i got

After running
>>> from website import db
>>> from website.models import Role
>>> role = Role(1, "teacher")
>>> db.add(role)

I got this error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/Users/mba/myCode/database_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 378, in add
return self._proxied.add(instance, _warn=_warn)
File "/Users/mba/myCode/database_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 197, in _proxied
return self.registry()
File "/Users/mba/myCode/database_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 632, in call
key = self.scopefunc()
File "/Users/mba/myCode/database_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/session.py", line 111, in _app_ctx_id
return id(app_ctx._get_current_object())  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
File "/Users/mba/myCode/database_final_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 508, in _get_current_object
raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
And i run
>>> from website.__init__ import create_app
>>> app = create_app()
>>> app.app_context()
<flask.ctx.AppContext object at 0x106f6b640>

i still get the same error message after running this command again
>>> db.session.add(arole)


SQLAlchemy doesn't require Flask. You can write a terminal script that uses it without Flask.

SQLAlchemy is a tool for connecting to databases, it isn't a database in itself.  Most databases have a command line client. On Mac/Linux the SQLite client is called sqlite3 (you may need to install it with your package manager).
